# Include the field in between the existing fields in html on buttonclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parent(".add1").remove()
  });
   $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    var clone = '<div class="add1"><input type="text" name="selprice" /><input type = "submit"    value = "+"    class = "add" ><input type = "submit"    value = "-"    class = "remove" ></div>';
    $("#container").append(clone);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container>
           <div class="add1">
           <h6>Other features </h6>
           <input type="text" name="selprice" />
           <input type="submit" value="+" class="add">
           </div>
           </div>
```

It works well!!But  I want to duplicate that field just next to the button clicked.

ie., If I enter '1' in the field and clicked on the '+' button ,It shows up the next field and If I enter '3' and again if I click on the 1st button which has the value of 1,the button should visible next to it.

[image: If I need a field in between 11 and 13,how should I do it]

Comment: Didn't you already make this question about 1 hour ago?

Comment: say clearly what you want

Comment: I can't able to duplicate the field inbetween 11 and 13(mentioned in attached image) when I click on the add button

Comment: Honestly, I think you might have to spend a bit more time on your question and make sure it makes sense to every, not just yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$("#container").append(clone)` to `$(this).closest('.add1').after(clone)` or `$(this).parent('.add1').after(clone)` or `$(this).parent().after(clone)`. Those should all work in this case.

`.append()` inserts the new element at the end of the selected container, whereas `.after()` inserts the new element directly after the selected element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $(document)
    .on("click", ".remove", function() {
      $(this).parent(".add1").remove()
    })
    .on("click", ".add", function() {
      var clone = '<div class="add1"><input type="text" name="selprice" /><input type="submit" value="+" class="add"><input type="submit" value="-" class="remove"></div>';
      $(this).closest('.add1').after(clone);
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container>
  <div class="add1">
    <h6>Other features </h6>
    <input type="text" name="selprice" />
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="add">
  </div>
</div>
```